# Gravity form auto populating field not working

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am using gravity forms for wordpress and and i have following function to auto populate the form field:

```
add_filter('gform_field_value_vendor_category', 'populate_post_vendor_category');
function populate_post_vendor_category($value){

global $post;
$vendor_category = the_terms( $post->ID, 'listing_category');
return $vendor_category;
}
```

Adding the parameter name `vendor_category` to the form does not seem to work.

I have tried the following code on a template file and it displays the current listing category.

```
<?php global $post;
$vendor_cat = the_terms( $post->ID, 'listing_category');
echo $vendor_cat; ?>
```

Not sure why the field is not auto populating?

Answer (score 0):

`the terms` is for echoing . Use [`get_the_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) instead for returning values.

```
get_the_terms( $id, $taxonomy );
```

as a rule of thumb, when you do not see the prefix `get_` in wordpress, the function will echo on the screen. like `the_title()` ( echoing ) and `get_the_title` (returning )..